# How to execute source command in docker-compose `command`?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run source in docker-compose `command` , like

```
command: ["source", "/etc/profile", ";", "/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

the error is

```
  ERROR: for pica-cat3  Cannot start service pica-cat3: b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \\"source\\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown'
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the builtin command from the shell which is embedded in your execution environment.

If `/bin/sh`, then run command `/bin/sh -c '. /etc/profile ; /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run`

If `/bin/bash`, then run command `/bin/bash -c '. /etc/profile ; /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run`

If `/bin/csh`, then run command `/bin/csh -c 'source /etc/profile ; /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run`